# Python TTS stops after 9 iterations. file is created, but no audio

Tags: text-to-speech

Raspberry PI, Python 3.7, program reads city list for weather conditions. Trying to output just the city name, e.g., New York, Detroit, etc. Program outputs the audio okay for first nine cities, afterwards the file is created but has no audio. Program loop is 240 seconds, 15 TTS per hour which is within the 100 TTS calls per hour limit. Python program continues, no errors, just no audio after the first nine cities. Restarting program after the tenth city, audio is okay but only for first nine cities, then no audio.
Appreciate any thoughts on this.

As said no Python program errors, restart works for 9 cities, then no audio.

Below are the two routines which run in a loop for each city [name]. The routines are called from main which send data to Nextion display.
`enter code here`

## TTS Name

```
def tts_name(name):
   global saveit
# TTS and Save City Name
   tts = gtts.gTTS(name)
   saveit = "Name.mp3"  
   tts.save(saveit)

# Play City Name
def Play_Name():
# Define Media Player file
   media = vlc.MediaPlayer("/home/pi/Nextion/OpenWeather_10/" + saveit)
# setting volume
   media.audio_set_volume(90)
#Play Name
   media.play()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: After media.play() added two lines: time.sleep(3) followed by media.stop() which corrected the issue.